# Is installing WordPress as a Git submodule a good idea?

Tags: wordpress, git, workflow, git-submodules

I'm curious as to others' workflow involving **Git and WordPress**, and whether or not you choose to install **WordPress** as a *submodule*. At first glance, it makes sense to keep my **Theme, Plugins, and Uploads** separate from the *wp core* files and easier to *update/maintain* over time.

Does anyone have any long-term experience and advice when it comes to developing **WP with Git**?

Does installing **WP as a Submodule** create any challenges when uploading the site to the Live Server?

Answer (score 0):

You have some projects which followed that approach before.

You can try and play with [`Darep/wordpress-boilerplate`](https://github.com/Darep/wordpress-boilerplate) (explained in [this article](http://ajk.fi/2013/wordpress-as-a-submodule/)):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Darep/wordpress-boilerplate.git
```

It has a Wordpress submodule, and include in the main parent repo `wp-content`.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I have Darep's boilerplate setup locally and it's great. I'm just wondering if there are any drawbacks of this approach down the road?

Comment: Glad to hear it. Thanks!